# Why is Takemichi not trying to claim power and money after going into the past?

Tags: tokyo-revengers

Takemichi can ask Naoto to search for some past events of that era. Takemichi can also go into the future and past anytime, so after going into the past, why doesn't he try to win some lottery or share market or something to get super-rich?

After becoming super-rich, he can control a lot of things. He can also save or hire the life of some highly-skilled boxer, martial artist, who then will guard him all the time. Right now, Toman and Mikey need the power to fight against Valhalla.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it could be a plot-hole and it could not be a plot-hole.

He probably just doesn't care about those things, his main goal is to save Hina (on the current state of the anime), and with that, he cares only about useful information about what happened for things to get like how it is on the future. Any other information, is useless since it won't help him, in his mission of saving Hina.

And as I said, probably a plot-hole as well, he really is wasting a good opportunity to get rich xD

Comment: he looks like a fool to me lol, you know money is power :D

Comment: Completely! That's a huge waste of opportunity to be the richest person in the world, but he still prefers love over money, while he could still do both lmao @SayedMohdAli

Comment: every time I think about this plot hole it sucks you know there are lot of Chinese dougha like this i.e tales of demons and gods. where the main character moved to the past to change the past but this takimichi sucks. 

you are right about his future goal is to save Hinata, but his past goal is to become head of Tokyo manji gang, with money and power he can easily own a lot of things, even he can leave Tokyo and can settle in some other place.